# Paypal Express option not appearing in checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2.4

I can't seem to make the paypal option appear for my magento installation. My setup is in the following

- MySQL 5.7
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.0
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Vanilla Magento 2.2.4 (No extensions installed)
- Vanilla Magento 2.1.12 (No extensions installed)

It is stated in 2.2.4's [release notes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.4CE.html) that this was already fixed

> PayPal Express Checkout now appears as a payment option on the
>   Checkout page when the PayPal buttons are available on the shopping
>   cart page. Previously, PayPal did not appear as a payment method on
>   the Checkout page when the billing agreement was disabled, although
>   the PayPal buttons were still available on the shopping cart page.

but after my testing it seems the problem still exists.

I've already tried the following to fix this problem by following the instructions on the links below:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10499#issuecomment-326604994
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10499#issuecomment-326976322
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10499#issuecomment-359028140
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10499#issuecomment-364390234
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12878#issue-284458104
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10499#issuecomment-326604994
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10499#issuecomment-326929588

It'd be great if anyone can help out. I've already wasted a lot of time in this issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue on 2.2.5 right now and no matter what I've tried, I can't get PayPal to show up at checkout. Figured I'd check in case you came up with something before I go digging into the core next week.

Answer (score 0):

After A lot of digging, I was able to make it work on my server. The problem was that the currency I am using (Philippine Peso - PHP) is not included in the `$_supportedCurrencyCodes` variable which can be seen in `vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Config.php line 207`.

`/**
   * Currency codes supported by PayPal methods
   *
   * @var string[]
   */
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = [
    'AUD',
    'CAD',
    'CZK',
    'DKK',
    'EUR',
    'HKD',
    'HUF',
    'ILS',
    'JPY',
    'MXN',
    'NOK',
    'NZD',
    'PLN',
    'GBP',
    'RUB',
    'SGD',
    'PHP', <--- I added my currency code here
    'SEK',
    'CHF',
    'TWD',
    'THB',
    'USD',
    'INR',
];`

After adding it and doing the following commands in the terminal:

```
root@server$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
root@server$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
root@server$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
root@server$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
root@server$ php bin/magento cache:clean
root@server$ php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I should also note that the Magento version I am using is `Magento 2.1.12`. I haven't tried in other Magento versions, but I think if the variable still exists in newer versions, It wouldn't be that hard to try it out.